# iTunes connect test user in live App?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have created an App with in-App purchase, and created multiple test users in iTunes connect. This has been working just fine.

After release I needed to do additional tests, but now I can't use a test user without adding my credit card info!

Is there anyway around this?
I do not want to pay for the in app purchase multiple times during testing!

Answer (score 2):

If it works in sandbox mode then it will work in production mode. You should be able to do all testing with dev and ad hoc builds in sandbox.

Comment: So the problem is that is if I have downloaded the App from the App Store, then I can't use a iTunes Connect Test user?